# How to .map() a JSON response from a get request and use the index that is inside the given index to determine table rows

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So this is what the JSON response looks like,
[image]

and what my project is displaying

[image]

and my render looks like this:

```
    render() {
    
    const { materials } = this.state;

    let returndata = _.isEmpty(materials) ? [] : materials
    console.log('look', returndata)
    
    return (  
        <div className="ui container"> 
        <br />
        <br />
            <Table fixed>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>UUID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Title</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Description</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                {returndata.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                    <Table.Row key = {i}>
                        <Table.Cell>{item.uuid}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{item.title}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{item.description}</Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>
                    )
                })}
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </div>
  );
}
```

what should I do to be able to show the data(16 items) from [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QWkv.png) without hardcoding them, because someday I might have more arrays and not just 0 and 1.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
const aggregated = data.reduce( (agg, list) => {
  return agg.concat(list.data)
}, [])

return ({aggregated.map((item, i) => Table.Row....})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<Table.Body>
   {
    returndata.map((item, i) => {
      return (
         <Table.Row key = {i}>
             {
             item.map(innerdata => {
             return(
                 <Table.Cell>{innerdata.uuid}</Table.Cell>
                 <Table.Cell>{innerdata.title}</Table.Cell>
                 <Table.Cell>{innerdata.description}</Table.Cell>
             )}
            )}
         </Table.Row>
      )}
   )}
</Table.Body>
```

The innerdata is part of an array inside the array.